# Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'ExerciseDAL.Department'

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, client-server

I am trying to display the department name when I enter an employees last name on the website interface and this is where I am having the problem!!! 
namespace ExerciseDAL
{
    public class DepartmentDAO
    {

```
    public DepartmentDAO() { }

    public Department GetById(string departId)
    {

        Department reDpt = null;
        DbContext _ctx;

        try
        {
            _ctx = new DbContext();
            var departments = _ctx.Departments;
            var dept = departments.AsQueryable<Department>().FirstOrDefault(dpt => dpt.Id.ToString() == departId);
            reDpt = dept;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem " + ex.Message);
        }
        return reDpt;
    }
}
}
```

As you can see departs is where I am getting Error CS0266. dept.id is an object and I have to compare it to a string, but when I did this way it would not compile.

Department Class:

```
 namespace ExerciseDAL
{
public class Department
 {
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; } //represents primary key
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
}
```

DepartmentViewModel: I will also be changing the code in here because I know this is wrong.

namespace ExerciseViewModel
{
    public class DepartmentViewModel
    {
        private DepartmentDAO _daos;

```
    public string DepartmentsId { get; set; } //represents primary key
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }

    public DepartmentViewModel()
    {
        _daos = new DepartmentDAO();
    }



    public void GetByDepart()
    {
        try
        {
            Department dpt = _daos.GetById(DepartmentsId);
            DepartmentsId = dpt.Id.ToString();
            DepartmentName = DepartmentName;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DepartmentsId = "not Found!";
        }
    }
}
}
```

DepartmentController: I will also be changing the code in here because I know this is wrong.

namespace ExerciseWebSite
{
    public class DepartmentController : ApiController
    {

```
    [Route("api/department/{departmentId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string departmentId)
    {
        try
        {
            DepartmentViewModel dpt = new DepartmentViewModel();
            dpt.DepartmentsId = departmentId;
            dpt.GetByDepart();
            return Ok(dpt);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("retrieve faild - " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Employee.js:

```
 $(function () {
$("#empbutton").click(function (e) {
    var last = $("#TextBoxLastname").val();
    ajaxCall("Get", "api/employees/" + last, "").done(function (data) {
        if (data.Lastname !== "not found") {
            $("#email").text(data.Email);
            $("#title").text(data.Title);
            $("#firstname").text(data.Firstname);
            $("#phone").text(data.Phoneno);

            ajaxCall("Get", "api/department/" + data.Id)
            .done(function (depdata)
            {
                $("#departmentname").text(depdata.DepartmentName);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            { errorRoutine(jqXHR); });
        }//end of if
        else {
            $("#firstname").text("Not Found");
            $("#email").text("");
            $("#title").text("");
            $("#phone").text("");
            $("#departmentname").text("");
        }//end of else
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    { errorRoutine(jqXHR); });//end of ajax
```

Comment: Can you please provide the actual code and not screenshots of code? See this article -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask -- Notably the "Help others reproduce the problem" section.

Comment: Okay, will do, I just thought this might be easier for people :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "from...where..." expression returns several departments, but you need only one.

Try this:

```
var dept = departments.Where(x=>x.Id == departId).Single();
```

Or change your reDpt object type from Department to something that allows multiple values, for example List.